# what is the command to create a soft link with haskell turtle?

Tags: haskell-turtle

which command creates a softlink with the turtle package? there is a command to copy a file: the command cp (which is in Turtle.Prelude) but how to make a soft link, i.e. the equivalent of ln -s ?

one could use used  shell or any of the related commands

```
shell "ln -s sourcefile target"
```

does work, but i assume there is a better way!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create symlink with Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153638/how-to-create-symlink-with-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command for this. Turtle tries to achieve portability across Windows, Linux and OS X. Creating symbolic links on Windows [is restricted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link#Restrictions), so it's unlikely that a platform dependant function gets exported in Turtle's prelude.

Also, the `Filesystem` module used by Turtle does not expose any symlink functionality. Therefore, you have to use `shell`, `proc` or another similar function.

Alternatively, use [`System.Posix.Files.createSymbolicLink`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#g:9). You have to include `unix` for this, though.