# How to create symlink with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, symlink

How to create a symlink with Haskell? The `directory` package to my knowledge does not provide a way to do it.

Comment: [System.Posix.Files.createSymbolicLink](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#g:9)

Comment: @n.m. Feel free to post as an answer, unless a duplicate question already exists.

Comment: Apparently there's a (near) duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369470/what-is-the-command-to-create-a-soft-link-with-haskell-turtle).

Comment: @n.m. I think this question will be easier to find via search engines, I think we should keep this one.

Comment: @Mark: Closing as a duplicate won't delete this question. Instead, it will still come up in search engines. (By the way, I knew I answered this question already somewhere :D)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating a symbolic link is non-portable. For example, the creation symbolic links on Windows [is re­strict­ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link#Restrictions)<sup>1</sup>. Therefore it does not fit into `directory` providing ["a basic set of operations for ma­nip­u­lat­ing files and directories in a **portable way**"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory) (emphasis mine). This affects all platform independent packages.

The platform specific package [`unix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix) provides that functionality in [`System.Posix.Files` with `createSymbolicLink`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#g:9) though:

```
import System.Posix.Files (createSymbolicLink)

main :: IO ()
main = createSymbolicLink "/opt/ghc/7.10.3" "/opt/ghc/active"
```

<sub>1: That's also a reason why `unix-compat` does not implement [`createSymbolicLink`](https://github.com/jystic/unix-compat/blob/master/src/System/PosixCompat/Files.hsc#L371-L378)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[directory-1.3.1 has](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.5/docs/System-Directory.html#v:createFileLink)

```
createFileLink :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
```

This is supposed to work even on Windows – only on a suitable file system, of course.